# Error deploying Python function using Google Cloud Functions using dependencies

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a simple function using Python 3.7. My setup looks like this:

**main.py**

```
from firebase import firebase

def hello_world(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return request.get_json().get('username')
    return f'Hello world!'
```

**requirements.txt**

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
requests==1.1.0
python-firebase==1.2
```

When deploying, I get this following error:

```
Deployment failure:
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file main.py can't be loaded.
Detailed stack trace: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 305, in check_or_load_user_function
    _function_handler.load_user_function()
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 184, in load_user_function
    spec.loader.exec_module(main)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from firebase import firebase
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase/__init__.py", line 3
    from .async import process_pool
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I solve this issue? I have all the required dependencies listed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `python-firebase` project was [last released on March 21, 2014](https://pypi.org/project/python-firebase/#history) by a third-party developer and doesn't support Python 3.7.  Specifically it uses the new reserved keywords `async`/`await`.

You probably want to use the [`google-cloud-firestore`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-firestore/) client library instead, which is maintained and supported by Google.